# Are these two ways of adding equivalent?

Tags: java

I am currently cramming for an exam in Java, and I was wondering if the two following approaches yields the same result apart from the null check? And if not, why?

Seatings is a collection,

```
public boolean addSeating(Group group) {

    //return seatings.add(createSeating(group));

    Seating seating = createSeating(group);
    if (seating != null){
        seatings.add(seating);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Depends; does the collection `seatings` allow `null`? If it does, then the two approaches are different. But **we** can't tell from what you have posted.

Comment: Moreover, from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-:

    Returns:
      true if this collection changed as a result of the call

If you were to try add two of the same seatings, you would return true both times, even though for arbitrary collections .add() might not modify the collection, eg. for a Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two approaches give different results.

### Version 1.

```
public boolean addSeating(Group group) {
    return seatings.add(createSeating(group));
}
```

This will:

1. return `true` if the newly created seating was added to the collection
2. return `false` if the new created seating was NOT added to the collection

Note that we do not *know* if `seatings` is a `List` or a `Set` or some other kind of collection:

- If `seatings` is a `Set`, then `add` will return `false` in the case that the element being added is already in the set.  (Or more precisely if it is *equal to* and element already in the set.)
- Other collection types *may* refuse the `add` for other reasons.  For example, a `List` class could refuse to add an element that was `null` or had the wrong type, or it could refuse the add if the list is "full" ... in some sense.

(If `seatings` is `ArrayList`, then the `add` will always succeed, so the result will always be `true`.)

### Version 2.

```
public boolean addSeating(Group group) {
    Seating seating = createSeating(group);
    if (seating != null){
        seatings.add(seating);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will:

1. return `false` if the newly created seating is `null`
2. otherwise return `true`

Note that the `true` result happens *irrespective* of whether a new seating was added.

Comment: I see, thank you! I should have pointed out that this is just a snippet of my code, and that "seatings" is an ArrayList.